# User.config in WPF Click once application saves at different location on using RunAsAdmin mode

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, clickonce, settings

I am using ClickOnce WPF application(.NET Framework 4.5.2) and I have added some User settings to my application. On update I save my user settings, using below code

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SomeSetting = "some value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

- if I run the **application without admin mode** : Then it prompts me to open in admin mode and application restarts in Admin Mode.
  So when I save the User Settings, they get saved at Location

  *C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local[CompanyName][ExeName]_Url_[some_hash][Version]\user.config*
- Now If I run the application setup for update in Admin Mode by Right Click **Option "Run As Administrator"** : then the application opens up normally 
  And on saving the User Settings, it gets save at different Data Location just in Directory where Application is deployed.

  *C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\ [some_hash]\ [some_hash]\ [some_hash]\ Data\ [Version] \user.config*

The problem is I want to retain the user settings on Upgrade of my WPF application. And location conflicts kind of provides different set of user settings. Does anyone faced similar issue, and can I just use only AppData\ Local for saving User.config in spite of any mode used to open application?